# Find matching records in same table different columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K, TLOCMTR.MTR_SRP_N, TLOCMTR.MTR_INST_D, 
    TLOCMTR.MTR_XCHG_OUT_D, RATE.RATE, TMTR.MTR_MFR_MOD_C, 
    TMTR.MTR_MFR_NM_CD
FROM
    TMTR 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    TLOCMTR ON TMTR.MTR_SRP_N = TLOCMTR.MTR_SRP_N 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    RATE ON TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K = RATE.LOCATN_K
WHERE
    ((RATE.RATE >= 20) AND (RATE.RATE <= 29)) 
    AND TLOCMTR.MTR_INST_D >= '2014-01-01' 
ORDER BY
    LOCATN_K, MTR_INST_D
```

The code results in:

[image]

What I need to do is count the number of times the MTR_MFR_NM_CD changes from AMP to <>AMP per Locatn_K where the MTR_INST_D = MTR_XCHG_OUT_D.  For example LOCATN_K = 85420005 went from AMP to EEM and the MTR_XCHG_D = MTR_INST_D 1 time (date was '2014-08-27'.  LOCATN_K 85430001 went from AMP to EEM 2 times on dates '2015-01-05' and '2016-01-12.

Please help me with some T-SQL to answer this!

Answer (score 0):

this is the essentials

```
select * 
  from ( select LOCATN_K, MTR_INST_D, MTR_MFR_NM_CD 
              , LEAD(MTR_MFR_NM_CD, 1,0) OVER (PARTITTION LOCATN_K BY ORDER BY MTR_INST_D) AS MTR_MFR_NM_CD_NEXT
           from 
           ...
        ) tt
 where MTR_MFR_NM_CD      =  'AMP'
   and MTR_MFR_NM_CD_NEXT <> 'AMP'
```

Comment: Im unfamiliar with lead and lag but just looked it up.  Doesn't look like I can use it in a where clause.  Just in the select clause?

Comment: Thanks @ Frisbee.  I tried this and made several modifications but this did not give the correct results.  I still got Amp to Amp and <>AMP to AMP.  I am only looking for records that go from Amp to <> AMP.  So exchange date has an AMP and Install date has <> amp.  I ended up splitting up the table and rejoining which gave me the results I was looking for.

Comment: That is just bizarre that does not work.  I cannot imagine how that would not work.  Those requirements are really hard to follow.

Comment: I can share what I did when modifying it?  Is there a way to add the code here after Ive posted the answer?

Comment: If what you have works then go with it.  You could add what you tried to you question of answer.  Format the problem statement so it is easier to read - it is a wall of text.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Frisbee's code with the following modifications but did not get the exact results:

```
select * 
from ( select TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K, TLOCMTR.MTR_SRP_N, TLOCMTR.MTR_INST_D, TLOCMTR.MTR_XCHG_OUT_D, TMTR.MTR_MFR_MOD_C, TMTR.MTR_MFR_NM_CD,
LEAD(TMTR.MTR_MFR_NM_CD, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K  
ORDER BY MTR_INST_D) AS MTR_MFR_NM_CD_NEXT
FROM TMTR RIGHT OUTER JOIN TLOCMTR ON TMTR.MTR_SRP_N = TLOCMTR.MTR_SRP_N 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE ON TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K = RATE.LOCATN_K
WHERE ((RATE.RATE >= 20) AND (RATE.RATE <= 29)) AND TLOCMTR.MTR_INST_D>='2014-01-01' AND TMTR.MTR_MFR_NM_CD = 'AMP'      
) tt
where tt.MTR_MFR_NM_CD = 'AMP'
and tt.MTR_MFR_NM_CD_NEXT <> 'AMP'
order by tt.LOCATN_K
```

This resulted in getting 'Amp' to 'Amp'  and <>'Amp' to 'Amp', but what I just wanted to get was 'Amp'to <>'Amp'.

The easiest way for me to do this was:

```
WITH A AS 
(SELECT  TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K, TLOCMTR.MTR_SRP_N, TLOCMTR.MTR_XCHG_OUT_D, TMTR.MTR_MFR_MOD_C, TMTR.MTR_MFR_NM_CD
FROM  TMTR RIGHT OUTER JOIN TLOCMTR ON TMTR.MTR_SRP_N = TLOCMTR.MTR_SRP_N LEFT OUTER JOIN  RATE ON TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K = RATE.LOCATN_K
WHERE ((RATE.RATE >= 20) AND (RATE.RATE <= 29)) and TLOCMTR.MTR_INST_D>='2014-01-01' AND TMTR.MTR_MFR_NM_CD = 'AMP'
),
B AS(
SELECT TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K, TLOCMTR.MTR_SRP_N, TLOCMTR.MTR_INST_D, TMTR.MTR_MFR_MOD_C, TMTR.MTR_MFR_NM_CD
FROM TMTR RIGHT OUTER JOIN TLOCMTR ON TMTR.MTR_SRP_N = TLOCMTR.MTR_SRP_N 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE ON TLOCMTR.LOCATN_K = RATE.LOCATN_K
WHERE ((RATE.RATE >= 20) AND (RATE.RATE <= 29)) AND TLOCMTR.MTR_INST_D>='2014-01-01' AND TMTR.MTR_MFR_NM_CD <> 'AMP' 
)

SELECT A.LOCATN_K, A.MTR_SRP_N AmpyMeter, B.MTR_SRP_N CreditMeter, B.MTR_INST_D EXCG_DT,  A.MTR_MFR_MOD_C AMP_MODEL, B.MTR_MFR_MOD_C Credit_MODEL
FROM A inner join B on A.MTR_XCHG_OUT_D = B.MTR_INST_D and A.LOCATN_K=B.LOCATN_K
ORDER BY LOCATN_K
```

My final results look like:
[image]